# Extract string inside class with xpath on scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the word WHITE in de following html

```
<p class="current">(WHITE)</p>
```

I'm using python-scrapy and it's only possible extract with Xpath. Using chrome, I get the xpath:

```
//*[@id="addToCart_pdp"]/div[3]/div[1]/p
```

Using scrapy I get

```
 hxs.select('//*[@id="addToCart_pdp"]/div[3]/div[1]/p')
 >> [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//*[@id="addToCart_pdp"]/div[3]/div[1]/p' data=u'<p class="current"></p>'>]
```

But can't get the word WHITE from this.

Answer (score 0):

`select` method on [HtmlXPathSelector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector) instance returns [XPathSelectorList](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.XPathSelectorList) object - basically it is a python list of `XPathSelector` objects (with few additional methods).

In order to get the text from the `HtmlXPathSelector` object you should change your xpath to get `text()` and call `extract()` method:

```
text = hxs.select('//*[@id="addToCart_pdp"]/div[3]/div[1]/p/text()').extract()[0]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's not the problem. I tried these combinations. I believe that the problem is that the HTML is generated differently and scrapy download the page and when I read this on my browser.

Comment: Well, I was just answering the question you've asked. Then, provide the URL you are trying to scrape from.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

then inside your request callback function (function name will be **parse** inside a spider) add these two lines:

```
sel = Selector(response)
print sel.xpath("//p[@class='current']//text()").extract()
```

this should get want you want.